# socket.io clients registration

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

Socket.io is a nice library to built real tima applications using the websocket protocol. I'm using it for the first time with node to build a chat application. I want to be able to register the clients and then authenticate them before they are able to create a socket connection and a room. I'm new to node, and I don't know how to register users and authenticate them, so I want to use php to register and login users, this also because I run my websocket server on heroku and the login and registration pages will be hosted on another server. Can anyone suggest me the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Generate an authentication token (with short expiry). Then use it to authenticate. Either,

1. Pass the token when initiating socket connection as a query param(not recommended)
2. Once connected, send a message to server via socket for authentication. On the nodejs side, if user is not authenticated within x seconds of connection terminate the connection.

Refer this article by me, I hope it's explanatory enough. It explain 2 possible scenarios for nodejs+ socket.io authentication.

https://medium.com/@prabathperera/web-socket-authentication-with-nodejs-socket-io-angular-b3c25e0862c6